# SQL Enterprise Manager R2

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

I would like to use SQL Enterprise Manager to manage my SQL Azure Databases. Everywhere I look everyone says that if you want to use the object browser then you need R2.

However I can not find Enterprise Manager R2 anywhere. Not unless I install DataCenter R2.

Where can I find Just Enterprise Manager R2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL Azure team recommends using SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio [Express] or Data Connections under Visual Studio 2010's Server Explorer.

You can download Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM - Management Studio Express from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=56ad557c-03e6-4369-9c1d-e81b33d8026b&displayLang=en).